# How to easily control spacing height between two paragraphs?

Tags: itext

Currently, I am using

```
document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
```

after each paragraph to generate space between two paragraphs. What is the way to generate a spacing of any height I specify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The space between two lines of the same `Paragraph` is called the *leading*. See [Changing text line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810133/changing-text-line-spacing)

If you want to introduce extra spacing before or after a `Paragraph`, you can use the [`setSpacingBefore()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#setSpacingBefore-float-) or [`setSpacingAfter()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#setSpacingAfter-float-) method. See [itext spacingBefore property applied to Paragraph causes new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945733/itext-spacingbefore-property-applied-to-paragraph-causes-new-page)

For instance:

```
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("First paragraph");
paragraph1.setSpacingAfter(72f);
document.add(paragraph1);
Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph("Second paragraph");
document.add(paragraph2);
```

This puts 72 user units of extra white space between `paragraph1` and `paragraph2`. One user unit corresponds with one point, so by choosing 72, we've added an inch of white space.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Bruno, do you happen to know of the solution to this display problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695541/strange-display-of-a-table-of-radio-buttons

Comment: I have commented on the answer @SamuelHuylebroeck and I leave it either to you to apply the tricks shown in the examples, or to Samuel to further elaborate on these examples in his answer.

Comment: If you use iText 7, you need to use setMarginBottom() instead of setSpacingAfter(). iText 7 syntax looks very much like HTML syntax