# Strange display of a table of radio buttons

Tags: itext

I am creating a form, in which there is a table of buttons. The following shows the idea:

```
             Good         OK         Bad

Item1      [button]    [button]    [button]
Item2      [button]    [button]    [button]
```

Each row is a button group.

My program is able to work for a small table like the above. However, when rows or columns are more than one page to hold, the display is weird. This is my program:

```
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(colHeaders.size() + 1  );
 table.setWidthPercentage(100);
 PdfPCell cell;

 table.setSpacingBefore(10);
 table.setSpacingAfter(0);
 table.setKeepTogether(false); //tested "true" different display error

 //upper-left corner empty cell
 cell = new CustomPdfPCell();
 cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
 table.addCell(cell);

 //header row
 for (TableOfChoicesHeader c: colHeaders) {
    String text = c.getText();
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.addCell(cell);
 }

 List<PdfFormField> radioGroups= new ArrayList<PdfFormField>();

 //for each row
 for (TableOfChoicesHeader r: rowHeaders) {

    //row header
    String rowText = r.getText();
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(rowText));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.addCell(cell);

 //for the current row row
 String fieldName = "question" + q.getId() +"_" + r.getId().toString();

 PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(writer, true);
 radiogroup.setFieldName(fieldName);

 radioGroups.add(radiogroup);

 for (TableOfChoicesHeader c: colHeaders) {     
     cell = new PdfPCell();
     cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
     cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
     cell.setPadding(5);
     cell.setCellEvent(new CheckboxCellEvent(fieldName, r.getId() + "_" + c.getId()));
     table.addCell(cell);                   
   }

 }
 document.add(table);

 for (PdfFormField g: radioGroups) {
    writer.addAnnotation(g);
 }
```

Here are the screenshots when `table.setKeepTogether(false)`. The display is a little different but still strange if the value is `true`.

Page 1
[image]

Page 2
[image]

**Update**

By following Samuel's approach, I am able to see radio buttons displayed on the first page. However, the buttons on the first page got displayed on the second page. See the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

I got it working by adding the following in MyCellField :

```
writer.addAnnotation(radiogroup);
```

instead of

```
PdfFormField field = radio.getRadioField();
writer.addAnnotation(field);
```

I cannot explain why. Thank Samuel and Bruno for their help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code again, is there any reason why you add the annotations for the radiobuttons all in one go at the end?.
Have you tried adding the annotation whenever you've added your row of cells? Something like this:

```
for (TableOfChoicesHeader r: rowHeaders) {

    //row header
    String rowText = r.getText();
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(rowText));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.addCell(cell);

    //for the current row row
    String fieldName = "question" + q.getId() +"_" + r.getId().toString();

    PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(writer, true);
    radiogroup.setFieldName(fieldName);

    radioGroups.add(radiogroup);

    for (TableOfChoicesHeader c: colHeaders) {     
         cell = new PdfPCell();
         cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
         cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
         cell.setPadding(5);
         cell.setCellEvent(new CheckboxCellEvent(fieldName, r.getId() + "_" + c.getId()));
         table.addCell(cell);                   
    }
    writer.addAnnotation(radiogroup)

}
```

EDIT:

As Bruno said, the examples for distributing a radio-group over multiple pages are [RadioGroupMultiPage1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples-itext5/creating-form-fields#1177-radiogroupmultipage1.java) and [RadioGroupMultiPage2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table#1178-radiogroupmultipage2.java). The examples for distributing a radio group across a table is found here: [Distributing radio buttons of a radio field across multiple PdfCells](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-distribute-radio-buttons-radio-field-across-multiple-pdfpcells).

EDIT 2, Electric Bogaloo:

Wipped up a quick example based on your code and the examples Bruno pointed out:
[image]

I basicly took your code frm the question above(with some stub-implementations for your custom data-classes), and used the `MyCellField` PdfCellEvent extension found in [RadioGroupMultiPage2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table#1178-radiogroupmultipage2.java):

```
   public MyCellField(PdfWriter writer, PdfFormField radiogroup, String value) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.radiogroup = radiogroup;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            RadioCheckField radio = new RadioCheckField(writer, position, null, value);
            PdfFormField field = radio.getRadioField();
            writer.addAnnotation(field);
            radiogroup.addKid(field);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // do nothing
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: Samuel, I tested it out before making the post. If I do that before document.add(table), none of the radio buttons shows up at all. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: Hi Samuel and curious1, please take a look at [RadioGroupMultiPage1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples-itext5/creating-form-fields#1177-radiogroupmultipage1.java) and [RadioGroupMultiPage2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table#1178-radiogroupmultipage2.java). You'll notice that special care is needed when distributing radio buttons over different pages.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your input. Looked at the two examples and can't figure out how they help here. Basically, the first example manually specify which page to place a radio button. The second example does not deal with paging directly, which is similar to my situation here, but I got strange display. Could you please be more specific about what I did is wrong? Best.

Comment: @curious1, I've updated my answer with an example. As to what you did wrong, my guess it can be found in the differences between your `CheckBoxCellEvent` implementation and the one in the samples.

Comment: Samuel, thanks sooooo much for going this far to help me. I followed your code. I see better results. I am able to see radio buttons on the first page. However, the buttons on the first page got displayed on the second page. Please see my updates in the post.

Comment: Samuel, I got it working and updated it in the post. I cannot explain why. If you can include it in your post and shed some light, I will select your post as the answer.

Comment: That is strange, since my code doesn't have the same issue, all buttons are nicely confined to the table and I don't have any spill/duplicates on my second page. I'll see if I can reproduce the duplication. My gut says you're adding duplicates somewhere because of some left-over trial code, but I can't confirm that without going over your final code.

Comment: Samuel, thanks so much for helping me! I upvoted all your comments. Since your solution inspired me to try different things and yours is close to what I have, I selected yours as the answer. Cheers!